# Strange symmetry of Haldane model edge

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, electronic-band-theory, topological-insulators

In the Haldane model we break both the inversion symmetry and time reversal symmetry, as a consequence I didn't not have any expectations when it comes to symmetry of the energy bands. However, to my big surprise, the energy bands for the armchair edge is symmetric under the $k$ -> $-k$ exchange. How can we explain this symmetry and why are the symmetry of the two cases different?

[[image: This image shows the energy bands for the armchair edge.[1]]

[image: As expected this plot for the zigzag edge does not posess this symmetry]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symmetry shown in the band structure here is not the consequence of inversion symmetry or time-reversal symmetry but the structure of hexagon lattice.

If the fermion system really has time-reversal symmetry (the Kane-Mele model for example), all kinds of band structures (zigzag, armchair, etc) will be symmetric around the origin because the time-reversal partner for an eigenstate is also an eigenstate for the system with the same eigenenergy but opposite crystal momentum. Besides, as far as I know, the inversion symmetry will not lead to apparent symmetry for band structures.

Back to your problem, the edge states can be viewed as the projections of the Dirac cones on the plane where the good quantum number is preserved. Recall that there are two Dirac points ($K$ and $K^{\prime}$) in graphene where the bulk gaps may close at. You can see that if you choose an armchair strip, $K$ and $K^{\prime}$ will be projected onto the same momentum, while if you choose a zigzag strip, $K$ and $K^{\prime}$ will be projected onto different momenta.

Comment: Sorry. There is an apparent mistake in my answer. The inversion symmetry will also lead to a symmetric band structure because the inversion operator also changes one eigenstate to another eigenstate with the same energy but opposite crystal momentum (if there is no other degeneracy for bands). The difference is that the inversion symmetry doesn't lead to the Kramers degeneracy.